# Oracle trigger before insert

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

here is my sample trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER INVOICES_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT ON INVOICES 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if :new.INVOICE_TYPE = 'Purchase'
    
    insert into Purchases (ID, Name, Type) Values (:new.ID, :new.Name, :new.Type)
END;
```

In my sample trigger, I get records both in Invoices and Purchases tables. But if the condition met in IF statement, I want to record data only into Purchases table.

Is it possible to do it in trigger.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: You want to catch all invoice 'Purchase' inserts and write a purchase row instead of an invoice row? While the person or process thinks they insert into invoice, you want to insert non-purchase rows into invoices and puchase rows into  purchases without the process or person knowing that this happens? They shall think they inserted into invoices, while this is not always the case?

Comment: If my assumtion is correct, why do you want to d this at all? Why have someone think they insert into one table, while the data goes to another? You can select all purchases and all non-purchases from the invoice table by simply applying a where clause. And you can even create views that show one data or the other for convenience. So why this tricky plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you wanted, not that way. Why? Because trigger fires before insert on `invoices` which means that row *will be* inserted into `invoices` table regardless of what you put into that trigger. Yes, you can - optionally - insert a row into the `purchase` table as well, but you can't avoid inserting into `invoices`.

Saying that you can't do it *that way*, I meant to say that there is, after all, another way to do it. How? Using a view and an instead of trigger. Here's an example.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table invoices
  2   (id       number,
  3    name     varchar2(10),
  4    type     varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create table purchase
  2   (id       number,
  3    name     varchar2(10),
  4    type     varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

View, a simple union:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_invpur as
  2    select id, name, type from invoices
  3    union all
  4    select id, name, type from purchase;

View created.
```

Instead of trigger: depending on the type, it inserts a row into appropriate table:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ioi_vinvpur
  2    instead of insert on v_invpur
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.type = 'invoice' then
  6       insert into invoices (id, name, type)
  7         values (:new.id, :new.name, :new.type);
  8    elsif :new.type = 'purchase' then
  9       insert into purchase (id, name, type)
 10         values (:new.id, :new.name, :new.type);
 11    end if;
 12  end;
 13  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into v_invpur (id, name, type)
  2    values (1, 'Little', 'purchase');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from invoices;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from purchase;

        ID NAME       TYPE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Little     purchase

SQL>
```

See? There's nothing in the `invoices` table, but a row is inserted into the `purchase` table.

Comment: thanks for your script, but it is not working, cause Invoices table has about 30 columns and purchases table has about 15 less. I got an issue in view union.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. UNION requires that SELECT statements have the same number of columns and that their datatypes match. Therefore, instead of those "missing" columns, CAST NULL to appropriate datatype. For example, `cast (NULL as number) col1, cast (NULL as varchar2(10)) col2, ...`.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this . . . such as `if`.  But a simple way is:

```
insert into Purchases (ID, Name, Type) 
    select :new.ID, :new.Name, :new.Type
    from dual
    where :new.INVOICE_TYPE = 'Purchase';
```

That is, the "conditional" logic can just be part of the `insert`.

Comment: this example inserts data only into Purchases table?

Comment: @Felichino . . . This inserts only purchases into the `Purchases` table.

Comment: yes, your code will work on simple script or inside stored procedure, but in trigger, it does not work

Comment: @Felichino . . . I'm not sure why you would say that.  `INSERT`s work fine in triggers.